# Running youtube-dl with C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, process, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download a Youtube video with youtube-dl using C#. I'm starting a new download process, but it seems like it isn't doing anything. If I start ipconfig for example, then it works. So the code should work.

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("youtube-dl", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0DPdy98e4c");
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
Console.WriteLine("output>>" + e.Data);
process.BeginOutputReadLine();

process.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
Console.WriteLine("error>>" + e.Data);
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

process.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: {0}", process.ExitCode);
process.Close();
```

Comment: So what happens if you run the command window yourself and type in the `youtube-dl` command?

Comment: Why are you launching cmd.exe instead of directly launching the program? Why aren't you using a .NET library that has download ability built in, instead of relying on an external program?

Comment: @Equalsk It runs perfectly if I start it manually.

Comment: @mason Youtube-dl is not just for youtube. It can download from a lot of sites.

Comment: Great - you still haven't addressed my other question.

Comment: Oh, sorry it has no effect if I start it directly

Comment: You should start it directly - there's no need to go through cmd.exe when launching the process from .NET.

Comment: I corrected the code.

Comment: Have you tried starting the Python interpreter, passing the name of the script as a parameter to it?

Comment: Do you have a try/catch wrapping this code?

Comment: What happens if you provide an absolute path to the youtube-dl executable, ex: `@"C:\youtube-dl.exe"`

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: @mason There isn't any errors.

Comment: @Sean I didn't try that yet. But I'm not using the script. I'm using the compiled exe.

Comment: I ran your code on my machine. It worked fine. I'll ask again: have you wrapped this code in a try/catch? Are you running this program on your own machine or a server? Is this a console application?

Comment: I wrapped it in a try/catch block. I'm running it on my own computer. It's in an async method. This is a console application.

Comment: I copied the whole code to another solution, and it works. I don't know why it isn't working in this solution.

Comment: You didn't show the async part or the try/catch. That's essential. You need to review [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

"youtube-dl.exe"; you missed the extension.

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("youtube-dl.exe", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0DPdy98e4c");
```